Can shot noise in a multi-species system always be expressed in terms of a Fano factor?
Consider a simple model of a two-species system of charge carriers $c$ and $d$ (say, both fermionic, with potentially different masses and dispersions but the same charge). Can the shot noise of such a system always be expressed in terms of a Fano factor?
Shot noise is in general defined to be the zero-frequency current fluctuation correlations: $$S = \int dt \langle \delta J\ \delta J \rangle$$
The Fano factor is defined as $$F = \frac{S}{2e\langle J\rangle}.$$
For the two-species system, we would have
$$S = \int dt ( \langle \delta J_c\ \delta J_c \rangle+ \langle \delta J_d\ \delta J_d \rangle + \langle \delta J_c\ \delta J_d \rangle + \langle \delta J_d\ \delta J_c \rangle)$$
Suppose that there is no interation between the $c$ and $d$ fermions. Then, we expect the cross-terms in the noise to be 0 (since no mechanism can correlate a current fluctuation of one species with the other). Say that $c$ fermions scatter off of some impurities, such that $\int dt \langle \delta J_c\ \delta J_c \rangle = S_c = 2e\langle J_c\rangle \frac{1}{3}$ (this is the well-known suppression of shot noise by impurity scattering). Simultaneously, let the $d$ fermions scatter weakly from impurities and interact strongly with each other, giving rise to some local equilibrium and $S_d = \int dt \langle \delta J_d\ \delta J_d \rangle = 2e\langle J_d\rangle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$.
If I now try to find the total shot noise, it looks like $S = S_c + S_d$ because the cross-terms are 0, which yields $$S = 2e\langle J_d\rangle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} + 2e \langle J_c\rangle \frac{1}{3}.$$
This clearly cannot be written as $S = F 2e \langle J_c + J_d\rangle$. Does anyone know if there is some generalization of the Fano factor for such a two-species system? I also wonder what happens if the cross-terms are nonzero (ie., there is some inter-species scattering).
